# Grails and Quartz: Bad value for type long

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to save quartz jobs into the database. I've set up the tables, created quartz.properties files, but when I try to run the app, this exception shows up:

```
2012-02-01 17:36:23,708 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'expirationTrigger' for 'com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJob' job:Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000]
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'expirationTrigger' for 'com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJob' job:Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000]
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'expirationTrigger' for 'com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJob' job:Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1241)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$5.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1147)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3670)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:242)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3666)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1143)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:790)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:254)
    at org.quartz.Scheduler$scheduleJob.call(Unknown Source)
    at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure24.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:223)
    at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure5.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:218)
    at QuartzGrailsPlugin.invokeMethod(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure3_closure21.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:169)
    at QuartzGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:167)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \254\355\000\005sr\000\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\237\260\203\350\277\251\260\313\002\000\000xr\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\202\010\350\303\373\305](\002\000\001Z\000\023allowsTransientDataxr\000\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\023\346.\255(v\012\316\002\000\002Z\000\005dirtyL\000\003mapt\000\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\001sr\000\021java.util.HashMap\005\007\332\301\303\026`\321\003\000\002F\000\012loadFactorI\000\011thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000\014w\010\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\001t\000'org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobNamet\000.com.pldtglobal.svngateway.ExpirationCheckerJobx\000
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2796)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2019)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet.getBlob(Jdbc4ResultSet.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBlob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:335)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3462)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:904)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1197)
    ... 36 more
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.
```

I don't have any idea on where the actual problem is. The code is alright and running when the jobs weren't saved in the database.

Comment: There's no accepted answer for this question. Did the below answer work for you? I'm running into the same issue and the below suggestion does not work for me.

Comment: @MichaelDJohnson Did you get this issue resolved ? How ?

Answer (score 32):

In your grails-app/conf/quartz.properties, replace

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
```

with

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

I'm getting the same error even using the correct delegate, so no promises.

Answer (score 21):

For spring boot, you can also specify the PG driver using the following property in application.properties -

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Answer (score 13):

For anyone using Quartz and Spring Boot, I had the same problem after migrating from using Quartz in Tomcat to Spring Boot. In Tomcat, we were using a quartz properties file and manually loading it when creating the Scheduler. One of those properties was:

`org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate`

In Spring Boot, the scheduler is created automatically through an auto config, and therefore our properties weren't being applied.

Our solution was to use a `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer` and set the Quartz properties. This customizer is applied before the scheduler is created so it's a good place to configure Quartz.

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer()
{
  return new SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer()
  {
     @Override
     public void customize(SchedulerFactoryBean bean)
     {
        bean.setQuartzProperties(createQuartzProperties());
     }
  };
}

private Properties createQuartzProperties()
{
    // Could also load from a file
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
    return props;
}
```

And for reference here is the full `quartz.properties` we migrated from:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=ProcessAutomation
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=QuartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource=springNonTxDataSource.ProcessAutomation
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

Comment: Could you please share the properties  you used.

Comment: @vkg sure, added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
    propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(props);
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Alternately if you want to set all quartz properties like clustered, thread-pool etc.. Instead of typing them here in this method, create a quartz.properties file and use below;

```
@Autowired
private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());

    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    return factory;
}
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/application.properties"));
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());
    propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(props);
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(); //it's important
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

quartz.properties file example below:-

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=springBootQuartzApp
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=50
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
#org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class=org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown=TRUE

Answer (score 1):

I also face this issue and I just add :

```
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
```

full bean configuration below

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(Trigger... triggers) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "MY_INSTANCE_NAME");
    properties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "INSTANCE_ID_01");
    properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
    schedulerFactory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
    schedulerFactory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
    schedulerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
    schedulerFactory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);

    if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(triggers)) {
        schedulerFactory.setTriggers(triggers);
    }

    return schedulerFactory;
}
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Sophea PHOS .

Answer (score 0):

Since this one was really hard to fix for us and none of these answers quite helped or would reference Grails specifically, I'll add what we needed to do to fix this issue:

We were using quartz plugin like so in a Grails 5.2.5 project:

```
implementation("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3") {
    exclude group: 'slf4j-api', module: 'c3p0'
}
implementation ('org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13')
```

Grails comes with Spring and Spring comes with its own Quartz scheduler, however, so we needed to turn off the Spring one, so it wouldn't mess with our own config (at some point we had jobs running twice, each run by its own scheduler). I figured they might have been reading each others props or something

To turn off the spring one we put in `application.yml` this:

```
spring:
    quartz:
        auto-startup: false
```

That helped.

Then we added to application.groovy this quartz configuration on top level:

```
quartz {
    jdbcStore = true // we needed this, because we were running more nodes and required jobs to run only once per set of nodes.
    autoStartup = false // autoStartup is set then to true per required environments.
    dataSource {
        quartzDataSource {
            driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            maxConnections = 30
        }
    }
    scheduler.instanceName = 'ourInstanceName'
    scheduler.instanceId = 'AUTO'

    threadPool.'class' = 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool'
    threadPool.threadCount = 15
    threadPool.threadPriority = 5

    jobStore.'class' = 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX'
    jobStore.driverDelegateClass = 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate'
    jobStore.dataSource = 'quartzDataSource' // this references the above datasource. The name needs to match but can be arbitrary
    jobStore.useProperties = false
    jobStore.tablePrefix = 'qrtz_'
    jobStore.isClustered = true
    jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 5000

    plugin.shutdownhook.'class' = 'org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin'
    plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true
}
```

and then per environment we'd set the rest of it e.g. like this:

```
environments {
    development {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = true
            dataSource {
                quartzDataSource {
                    user = 'grails'
                    password = 'grails'
                }
                quartzDataSource.URL = 'ourUrl' // I had to move URL outside like this, because if it was just URL without the prefix inside the above curly braces, the app wouldn't run with error "you tried to assign a value to the class 'java.net.URL'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the various quartz properties are set directly in the `quartz` node not in `quartz.props` or `quartz.properties` nodes, like it was before. It wouldn't work there.

And in case you'd also need it, here's the scripts for creating the required quartz db tables. We've been looking for it for a while. https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/database/tables/tables_postgres.sql