# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quartz

I am using Quartz API 2.3.0 with  Spring boot Parent 2.0.5 and postgresql version 9.2-1002-jdbc4.
I get below error when the application retrieves data from ***qrtz_job_triggers*** table.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'schedulerFactoryBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Bad value for type long : \x [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x]]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265)
    at com.ericsson.cis.healer.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Bad value for type long : \x [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x]]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:697)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:539)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:707)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:779)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Bad value for type long : \x
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1538)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:984)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:871)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$1.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:843)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3765)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3763)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3849)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:839)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:695)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2971)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2163)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBlob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:378)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBlob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:366)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getBlob(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3190)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1780)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1536)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Below is the script for the table

```
    CREATE TABLE qrtz_job_details
(
  sched_name character varying(120) NOT NULL,
  job_name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  job_group character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(250),
  job_class_name character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  is_durable boolean NOT NULL,
  is_nonconcurrent boolean NOT NULL,
  is_update_data boolean NOT NULL,
  requests_recovery boolean NOT NULL,
  job_data bytea,
  CONSTRAINT qrtz_job_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (job_group, job_name, sched_name)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE qrtz_job_details
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I have also tried  With other postgres version i.e. 42.2.5

My ***application.properties*** file

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cis_migration
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=first
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grails and Quartz: Bad value for type long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094505/grails-and-quartz-bad-value-for-type-long)

Comment: Hi All,

This is resolved. I reviewed the code again and found that the SpringQuartzfactoryBean was not picking the right properties file and hence the issue. 
I was already trying the solution in the given link but was not only getting picked due to wrong property being read.

Comment: @SternK Thanks for the pointer.